# automatically unmount sshfs network drives before VPN disconnects on suspend

Tags: mount, suspend, vpn, sshfs

Reasonably new linux user here. For my work, I regularly mount two network drives via sshfs in Xubuntu 15.05. Now I've written a little bash script to mount/unmount both drives & create a symlink to them in local bin to make things easier for myself, and they work fine. The problem is that I can only mount these network drives when VPN is connected, and when I suspend my laptop (which I sometimes have to do very unexpectedly) the VPN connection gets broken without the disks being unmounted. After resuming the session later, the disks seem to be stuck between mount and unmount. I cannot access the disks, but I can also not unmount them, or even remount them. Does anyone know a way to make sure that any time the VPN connection  is broken for some reason (either on suspend, or because the network fails or whatever reason) both disks are automatically unmounted just before to prevent this problem?

Thanks so much!
Narameh

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Make script witch will `umount` `sshfs` drives when `vpn` is terminated.

Make script in the folder `/etc/network/if-down.d/` with execute permissions 755

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "ppp0" ] || exit 0
# Do something

umount /path/drive
```

When `int ppp0` will go down command `umount /path/drive` will be executed

Also you can make "auto mount" if `int ppp0` go up

Make script in `/etc/network/if-up.d/`

```
# Check for specific interface if desired
[ "$IFACE" != "ppp0" ] || exit 0
# Do something

your_script_for_mounting_drives
```

Solutin No 2

Make script `link_stat`

`nano /path/link_stat`

```
#!/bin/bash

if ip addr show ppp0 | grep 'state UP'; then
    echo "Network ok."
else
    echo "$ERR Network down, umounting"
    #put_here_your_sommand_for_umount
fi 2>&1 >> /path_to_log/stat_log
```

do

```
chmod 777 /path/link_stat
```

Run script with cron

`sudo crontab -e`

run command on every 30 sec

```
* * * * * /path/link_stat
* * * * * sleep 30 && /path/link_stat
```

This will check for `vpn` status and if status if dovn will be umount drives

Comment: Apologies for this very late reply. Thanks very much for this expansive answer. I've since reinstalled and chosen to mount without needing VPN, which has solved the problem entirely :).

Comment: Great. Problem solved :)